# Selling Chometz to a young gentile

Tags: gentiles, transactions, minor-katan-child, selling-mechirat-chametz

May the sell of chometz be done with a young gentile that in Judaism would be considered a "katan" in terms of halacha and therefore perhaps wouldn't be able to have his buying and selling be "valid" according to Halacha?

I suppose this question would apply to many other halachos however I'm asking it now with this example because it is from inyunei d'yoma.

Comment: I have no sources, but as the transaction needs to also be valid by civil law, and a minor cannot sign contracts, it would seem that selling to a katan would be prohibited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sharei Teshuvah on Orach Chaim 448:15 he quotes Sh"ut Veshav Hakohen who concludes that Bdi'avad -especially by Chometz Derabanan- one could rely on those who say that a Koton is Koneh rental of property.

Comment: @Mekubal The link to the article from R' Hoffman is not working. Did he quote this? I'm surprised if it wasn't quoted. Would have saved the whole article ;).

Comment: I'm just wondering what would constitute Chometz Derabanan?

Comment: I'm guessing Chometz Sheovar Alav Es Hapesach.

Comment: That's the only example of "chometz d'rabbanan"?

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Yair Hoffman just wrote an article on this [that can be found at this link.](http://5tjt.com/does-the-gentile-who-buys-the-chometz-need-to-be-bar-mitzvahed-by-rabbi-yair-hoffman/)  He goes through a number of sources from the Gemarra through the Rishonim and into the Achronim, and is well worth the read.  For those who want just the conclusion it is this:

> It would seem that in order to avoid a debate on the matter, one
>   should most definitely be stringent and transact the sale only with a
>   mature, adult non-Jew.

Comment: His article is about liability for _mitzvos b'ne Noach_. His final paragraph, which you quote, is about maturity for conducting transactions: but I don't see how he gets to that from the rest of the article. It seems quite a leap.

Comment: One naturally leads to another.  A contract cannot be conducted with a minor who lacks understanding.  He is trying to determine the age of accountability for a non-Jew.

Comment: Yes, a contract cannot be conducted with a minor who lacks understanding. Yes, he is trying to determine the age of accountability for a non-Jew. But who says understanding and accountability are reached simultaneously -- especially (but not only) according to the views he cites that accountability starts at birth? I'm not blaming *you*: you found an answer, cited it, quoted it. But I don't see where *he* gets it from.